# How to detect changes between tables with CDF Databricks?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, cdc, cdf, delta

I have data pipeline, in the pipeline i need to detect change in three different table, except that , one of those table could be have no change.

Example:

---

First Table

| id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Second Table

| id | category_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | test1 |
| 2 | 2 | test2 |

Third Table

| id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fruits |
| 2 | vegetable |

With these three tables, how do i do it, if for example the category with id 2 changes, but not the corresponding line in the first table, I would not see the change in my cdc of the first table, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: @ Paul Douane  Are you using AWS or Azure databricks or community edition?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula I use gcp databricks